# Why does my random number only return 0?

Tags: java

I'm working in a coding class with IntelliJ Idea and I decided to make a project for fun. Here is my code. Note that java.util.Random is already imported:

```
    public static void generateForest(){
        int[][] forest = new int[50][50];
        Random ran = new Random();
        double randBounds = 150;
        double incr1 = 1.05;
        double incr2 = 1.07;
         for (int i = 0;i<50;i++){
            for(int q = 0;q<50;q++){
                try {
                    double ranNum = ran.nextInt(Math.abs((int) Math.round(randBounds)));
                    if (Math.round(ranNum)==0){
                        forest[i][q] = 0;
                    }
                    else {forest[i][q] = 1;}
                }
                catch(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException e){
                    forest[i][q] = 0;
                }
                if (q<=25){
                    randBounds = (randBounds/incr2);
                }
                else{randBounds = (randBounds*incr2);}
            }
            if (i <=25){
                randBounds = (randBounds/incr1);
            }
            else{randBounds = (randBounds*incr1);System.out.println(randBounds);}
        }
        printTrees(forest);
    }
```

printTrees just prints out the array input in the manner you see in the screenshots. 
The outputs generally looks like this:

[image: Output]

My code is supposed to essentially generate a sort of forest, with the trees being the Ts, and the bottom half is supposed to sort of mirror the top half. However, the bottom half is just entirely Ts. How can i fix it so that the bottom half is random in a similar pattern to the top half, only reversed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 75% of this code is not relevant to your problem.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer that most solve your problem. You've asked 5 questions so far and accepted none!

Comment: If you want the bottom half to mirror the top half, then why not fill the bottom half randomly i.e. `index 25 - 49` and then reverse loop and fill the top half i.e. `index 25 and 24` are identical and `index 26 and 23` are identical and so on. `i++` -> `j--`

Comment: You told it to return 0 when an IllegalArgumentException is thrown, and it's throwing a lot of them.

Comment: @SeanVanGorder Yes, I am aware it is throwing a lot of them, but no matter what I try to do, the second half either looks really weird or the randBounds variable is less than one.FortyTwo; I want it to be random, but in a similar pattern to the first half reversed. you're suggesting that i just mirror the two.
assylias; a debugger wouldn't help in this situation.

Comment: And following on from @SeanVanGorder's point: catching and swallowing unchecked exceptions (like IllegalArgumentException) is rarely the right thing to do: they indicate programming errors (as opposed to checked exceptions, which indicate failures beyond your control), and so you should actually fix the code instead.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, i'm trying to figure that out. What's happening is that randomBounds is too small of a number and Random doesn't accept it (at least I think so).

Comment: @WhyIsCode what are you actually trying to do here? Why not just create a tree with random probability `x`? Also a debugger would help you figure out why Random isn't accepting a number.

Comment: The image is removed!

Comment: To get rid of rounding use integers

Comment: @WhyIsCode Curious to hear why you think a debugger wouldn't help in a situation where the code does not do what you expect it to do.

Comment: @River I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that, and additionally, I don't know how to use the debugger in IntelliJ.

Comment: @WhyIsCode The second part of your comment explains the first half =) The debugger let's you see what values are being passed around in your code. [Check this out](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugger-basics.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by [@SeanVanGorder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2643425/sean-van-gorder) in the comments, you're hitting the `IllegalArgumentException` case frequently, so you are always choosing zero for the "random" value. ([Sounds like an xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/221/)).

The only thing in the try/catch block that would throw this exception is the call to `Random.nextInt(int)`, which is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) as throwing `IllegalArgumentException` if the parameter is not positive. So, your parameter, `Math.abs((int) Math.round(randBounds))` is not positive.

The reason it isn't positive is it becomes zero. It's easy to see why:

- Starting from 150
- You divide it by 1.07 twenty-six times
- You multiply it by 1.07 twenty-four times
- So its value of `randBounds` after executing all 50 iterations of the `for(int q = 0;q<50;q++){...}` loop is `150 / 1.07 ^ 26*1.07^24 = 150 * 0.873 = 131`
- You then divide `randBounds` by 1.05, so it becomes `150 * 0.873 / 1.05 = 150 * 0.831 = 124.7`, and repeat these divisions/multiplations another 26 times (iterations of the outer loop). At the end of these 26 iterations, `randBounds` is just 1.25.
- Then you repeat the inner loop (which makes `randBounds` 0.873 times the size per iteration, but are now *multiplying* by 1.05 instead of dividing by 1.05. But the overall change to `randBounds` per iteration is `0.873 * 1.05 = 0.917`, i.e. you're still decreasing its magnitude.

  Starting at 1.25 and decreasing the magnitude by 0.917 times, you're going to drop below 0.5 after just 10 iterations. As such, once you've done 36 iterations of the outer loop, `randBounds` is less than 1, and you'll always get the `IllegalArgumentException`.

*However*, you will start to get zeros all the time once `0.5 <= randBounds < 1.5`, since that rounds to 1, and `Random.nextInt(1)` always returns zero. So, actually, you will start getting all zeros earlier than that 36 iteration mark. In fact, this happens after 25 iterations of the outer loop.

It's hard to suggest a fix, because it's unclear what the correct behavior is; the only general fix is to recognize that unchecked exceptions (like `IllegalArgumentException`) *shouldn't* be caught and swallowed, as they indicate programming errors.

Comment: Also, don't be assigning `int` values to `double` variables then narrowing them to `int` right away, as in `double ranNum = ran.nextInt(...; if (Math.round(ranNum) ...`. Format your code conventionally and simplify your logic. It'll make it easier to find and fix your bugs.

Comment: So what would be the optimal way to have the chance of a tree increase as it goes down/to the right, and start decreasing once it reaches index 24?

Comment: I'm not sure how,  but after a small bit of messing around, I was able to fix it. In fact, I'm not even sure how it worked. all I did was slightly adjust the variables and it greatly affected how low randbounds went. I changed the index test to 24 instead of 25, and even increased the increments. Now randBounds only goes down to about 3.4 with the outside loop. Not sure how that ended up working, but your answer definitely helped me.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a Gaussian distribution would be more to your liking:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate;

import java.util.Random;

public class StackOverflow45044823 {

  public static void populateField(final char[][] field) {
    Validate.noNullElements(field);
    final Random random = new Random();
    for (int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < field.length; rowNumber++) {
      for (int columnNumber = 0; columnNumber < field[rowNumber].length; columnNumber++) {
        //random.nextGaussian() / 6.0 =  stdev=1/6 center=0
        //rowNumber / (float) field.length - 0.5 = grows uniformly from -0.5 to 0.5
        if (random.nextGaussian() / 6.0 < rowNumber / (float) field.length - 0.5) {
          field[rowNumber][columnNumber] = 'T';
        } else {
          field[rowNumber][columnNumber] = ' ';
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final char[][] treeField = new char[50][50];
    populateField(treeField);
    printField(treeField);
  }

  private static void printField(char[][] field) {
    Validate.noNullElements(field);
    for (char[] aField : field) {
      System.out.println(StringUtils.join(aField, '|'));
    }
  }
}
```

It yields something like...

```
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |T| | | | | | | | | 
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 
 | | | | | | |T| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |T| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |T| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |T| | | | | 
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | |T| | | | | | |T| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |T| | | | 
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |T| |T| | | | | | | | 
 |T| | | | | | | | | | |T| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |T|T| 
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |T| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |T| | | | |T| | 
 | | | | | | | | | | | |T| | | | |T| | | | | |T| |T| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 
 | | | | | | | | | | | |T|T| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |T| | | | | | 
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |T| | | | |T| | | | | | | | | |T| | | | |T| | | | | |T| | | | 
 | | | | | |T| | | | | | |T|T| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 
 | | | | | | | | |T|T|T| | | | |T| |T| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |T| | | | | | 
 | | | | |T| | | | |T| | |T| | | | | | |T| | | | |T|T|T| | | | | | | |T| | | | | |T| | | |T| | | | 
 | |T| | | |T| | | | | | | | |T| | | |T| | | | | | |T|T|T|T| | | | |T| | |T| | | | | | |T| | | | |T
T|T| | | | | | | | |T| | | | |T| | |T| | | | |T|T|T| | | | | | | | | | | |T| | | |T| |T| | | | | | 
 | | |T| |T| | | | | |T| | | | | | | | |T| | | | | |T| |T|T| | | |T| | | | |T| | | |T| | |T| |T| | 
T| | |T|T|T|T| |T|T|T| |T| | |T| |T| |T|T| | |T|T| | | |T|T| |T|T| |T|T|T| | |T| | |T|T| |T| | | |T
T| |T|T| | | |T|T| | | | | |T|T| | | |T| | | | | |T|T|T| |T| |T| | |T|T|T| |T|T|T|T| | | | | |T| | 
T| | | |T|T| | |T|T| |T| | | | | |T|T|T|T|T| | | |T|T| | | | | | |T|T| | | | | |T| | | |T|T| | | |T
T|T| | |T| |T| | |T| | |T| | | | | |T| |T|T| | | |T|T|T| |T|T|T| | |T| |T| |T| | | | | |T|T|T|T| |T
 | |T| |T|T|T|T| |T| |T|T| |T|T| |T| | |T|T|T|T| |T| |T| |T| |T| |T|T|T| |T| | |T|T| |T| |T| |T|T| 
 | |T| | | |T|T|T| |T| |T| |T| |T| |T|T| |T| |T|T| | |T|T|T|T| | | | |T|T|T|T|T| |T| |T|T|T| |T|T| 
 |T|T|T| |T|T| | | |T|T|T| |T|T|T| |T|T| | |T|T| | | |T| | |T|T| |T|T|T|T| | | |T|T| |T|T|T| |T| |T
T|T|T| |T|T| |T| |T| | |T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T| |T| |T|T|T|T| |T|T
T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T| | |T|T|T| |T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T| |T| |T|T| |T|T|T|T| |T|T
T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T| |T| |T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T| | |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T| |T| |T|T|T|T|T|T
T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T| | |T|T|T|T|T| |T| |T|T|T|T| 
T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T| | |T
T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T| |T|T| |T|T
T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T
T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T| | |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T
T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T
T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| | 
T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T
T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T
T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T
T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T
T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T| |T| |T|T|T
T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T
T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T
T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T
T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T
T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T
T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T|T
```

Comment: Ah, this does look good, however, I'm trying to make it most populated in the very center, and more scattered around the four edges.

Comment: Additionally, what does
    Validate.noNullElements(field);
do? I'm pretty new to this language

Comment: `Validate.noNullElements(field);` verifies that field is not null and that all elements in field are not null. I want to make sure my input is valid before trying to operate on it.

Comment: @WhyIsCode If that's your goal, you could use the indexes to determine how far from the center you are and use that as your probability, instead of adjusting the probability from the previous box.